# Getting broken image icon when displaying image from online url in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, image, frontend

The webpage display is fine otherwise. [but the images show up like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8Lkr.png)

my code is   `<img src = {props.imageUrl} />` and console.log(prop) returns

```
{...imageUrl: "https://unsplash.com/photos/3PeSjpLVtLg"...}
```

What could be the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The url is a web page. It is not a url to an image so an `image` tag won't be able to display it. In the case of this  specific image, you want the url to be this:

```
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601439678777-b2b3c56fa627?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the require to the src image like this:

```
<img src = { require(props.imageUrl)} />
```

Another way around would be in the props adding the require :

Example:

```
 const slides = {
 imageUrl: require('url'),
}
```

and leave your code as it is in the  `<img src = {props.imageUrl} />`